# What is the CCOptions options = 0x3 for CCCrypt?

Tags: objective-c, encryption

I've seen some developers use CCOptions options = 0x3.

In the documentation, however, https://opensource.apple.com/source/CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto-36064/CommonCrypto/CommonCryptor.h, I only see default (CBC), 0x1 (PKCS7 Padding), and 0x2 (ECB); I don't see 0x3.

What mode is 0x3?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit field: options can be combined.

0x03 has bit 0 (0x01) and bit 1 (0x02) set, so it's the combination of *PKCS7Padding* and *ECB mode*.

Or in other words:

```
kCCOptionPKCS7Padding | kCCOptionECBMode == 0x03
```